# ERC20 finishMinting() after ICO

Tags: erc-20, ico, openzeppelin-contracts

When ICO is finalized, I call `finishMinting()` to prevent from adding new tokens to totalSupply.

```
contract MyTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, WhitelistedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {

...

 function finalization() internal {
    if(goalReached()) {

   MintableToken _mintableToken = MintableToken(token);
   _mintableToken.finishMinting();
 }
}
```

However, if I want to deploy another crowdsale as a second round of ICO, I'm not sure how to set `mintingFinished` back to false again so people can `buyToken` again.

```
  function finishMinting() public onlyOwner canMint returns (bool) {
    mintingFinished = true;
    emit MintFinished();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: You could just write a function `unFinishMinting()` that does `mintingFinished = false`. But I think that defeats the purpose of `finishMinting`. :-)

Comment: @smarx ok. Does that mean I should block people from buying tokens from UI level as soon as the first ICO is completed and should not call `finishMinting`?

Comment: You're the one writing the contract. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know what you want to do, and without seeing the code for the contract, I don't even know what the current code does. But I _can_ tell you that blocking functionality in some UI has no effect on what people can do with your contract.

Comment: You're right, blocking it from UI would have no effect. So yeah.. I am the one writing the contract, but at the same time I am using open-zeppelin as people claim that it's the industry standard. That's why I am curious to know the reason they didn't implement a function such as `unFinishMinting()` as you mentioned in the comment. Because there are actually certain cases where some companies are launching a couple of ICOs with their token. Any idea how they are dealing with this case with open-zeppelin?

Comment: I have no idea. If you've seen smart contracts that do that, try reading their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using an older version of OpenZeppelin.  OpenZeppelin moved to a more granular system of roles in [OpenZeppelin 2.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

I would suggest that you use the latest version, [OpenZeppelin 2.3](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/releases/tag/v2.3.0)

Using MinterRoles gives you more flexibility e.g. you could assign your first and second crowdsales a MinterRole and then each crowdsale could renounce their MinterRole when they have finished.

The [OpenZeppelin documentation on Crowdsales](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales) is a good place to start to look at some of the different options, along with [documentation on Role Based Access Control](https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/access-control#roles-role-based-access-control)

If you have more questions about OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions)